# Running Python Script in PyCharm Debugger with `proxychains`

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, proxychains

I am working with PyCharm IDE and have encountered an issue where I need to run my Python script within both the PyCharm internal debugger and under `proxychains`. The reason for using proxychains is that the modules I'm working with do not support working via a SOCKS5 proxy, which is necessary for internet access.

Running the script directly from the internal debugger does not provide an option to use `proxychains`, and using the built-in console does not allow me to step through the code with the debugger.

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to run my script with both the internal debugger and `proxychains`? I want to be able to debug my code while also routing network requests through `proxychains`. Any help or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

IDE version: PyCharm 2021.3 (Community Edition) under Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating a shell script which would run your script through ProxyChains and then using this script as an interpreter in PyCharm.

First, create a shell script named `python` in your project directory (let's say it's located at `~/MyProject`):

```
#!/bin/sh
proxychains4 /usr/bin/python3 "$@"
```

`$@` is used to pass all the arguments (specifically, path to your main script) through this script to the actual Python interpreter (`/usr/bin/python3`).

Make this script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/MyProject/python
```

Now we can add this script as an interpreter in PyCharm.

If you're not using a virtual environment for this project, you can just [add a new system interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2021.3/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html) and pick the created `python` shell script (`~/MyProject/python`) as the executable. Then add a new configuration using this new interpreter and path to your main script.

If you need a virtual environment for this, [create a new virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2021.3/creating-virtual-environment.html), specify its location and path to your default python interpreter (say, `/usr/bin/python3`), install all the necessary dependencies inside it and then once again go to `Preferences -> Python Interpreter -> Show all`, select your newly created virtual environment and change the "interpreter path" field to the shell script path (`~/MyProject/python`).

And one more step. Since PyCharm's debugger uses a built-in local server, you need to exclude connection to it in `proxychains.conf`:

```
localnet 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
```

Voilà!

```
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.17/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.17
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.17
Connected to pydev debugger (build 233.13763.11)
[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  171.244.140.160:3991  ... api.ipify.org:443  ...  OK
{'ip': '171.244.140.160'}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Debugger throws a lot of warnings, but it works!
`pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)`
`pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints`
`pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen codecs>`

Comment: A little fix: For a virtual environment, the script should contain the path to the appropriate virtual environment interpreter, not the system-wide `/usr/bin/python3`. Also: I emphasize that in order to get PyCharm to accept the new path for the interpreter, the script must be called exactly `python` or `python3`, and not like `proxy_python.sh` (as I tried at first) or any other name.